# mxmlc attributes for release build

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, mxmlc

Which mxmlc attributes do I need to replicate the behaviour of Flash Builder 4's Export Release Build?

debug=false and optimize=true seems obvious, but doesn't reduce the swf's file size as FB4's Export Release Build does.

Comment: have you compared the two SWFs ? have a look here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_13.html

Answer (score 2):

Flash Builder use RSLs by default.

There is a documentation about how to use RSL with the command line [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=rsl_09.html)